# Prove that $py^{p-1}(x-y)<x^p - y^p<px^{p-1}(x-y), (0<y<x,p>1)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I don't know how to proof the following question:
$$py^{p-1}(x-y)<x^p - y^p<px^{p-1}(x-y),(0<y<x,p>1)$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Mean value theorem does it.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more, I'm a first year student and I don't know value theorem. :(

Comment: It's actually easier than that.  To get the right inequality divide both sides by $x^{p-1}$.

Comment: Didive through $x-y$ and expand $x^p-y^p=(x-y) \sum_{k}x^{k}y^{n-k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JPi says:

Let $f(x) = x^p$
with $p > 1$.
By the mean value theorem
we have
$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}
= f'(c)
$
where 
$y < c < x$.

We also have
$f'(x) =px^{p-1}> 0$
and
$f''(x) =p(p-1)x^{p-2}> 0$.

Since
$f''(x) > 0$,
$f'(y) < f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} < f'(x)$,
which is what you want.

Note that
if $0 < p < 1$,
then
$f''(x) < 0$,
so the inequalities are reversed:
$f'(y) > f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} > f'(x)$.

Comment: Excuse me, why do we compute the second derivative? Thank you

Comment: If f'' > 0, f' is increasing; if f'' < 0, f; is decreasing.

Comment: Hmm.. I understand now, thanks a lot for answering

Answer (score -1):

let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ so
$$
p \alpha^{p-1} \lt \alpha^{p-1} + \alpha^{p-2}+\dots+ \alpha +1 \lt p
$$multiplying through by $1-\alpha$ gives:
$$
p\alpha^{p-1}(1-\alpha) \lt 1-\alpha^p \lt p(1-\alpha)
$$
now set $\alpha = \frac{y}x$ and multiply through by $x^p$